# An issue I encountered when I was using the import tool galaxybase-load

Tags: graph-databases

I received the following prompt while using the import tool galaxybase-load: "The graph name is inconsistent with the graph name in the Schema."

What does the inconsistency refer to? I don't know which graph name it's talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompt indicates an "inconsistent graph name," which means that the graph name specified by the -g parameter in the command line does not match the graph name specified in the "graphName" field of the schema.json.